# How to correctly read Latin 1 character from postgre database using C++

Tags: character-encoding

I have imported a shapefile in postgre database where Latin1 character encoding is used. (Database can not import using UTF-8 format). When I retrieve value using PQgetvalue() method some special characters are received incorrectly. For example I have a field value "STURDEEÿAVENUE"  that is incorrectly converted 
to "STURDEEÃ¿AVENUE"

Comment: Your connection is in UTF-8 it seems. Set client_encoding properly?

Comment: My client encoding is UNICODE(I just saw using show client_encoding). How is this related to my problem? Can you please explain? @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: The data is transferred based on the client_encoding. You can set it separate for each connection and if it's set to latin1 you'll get the data correctly.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot @SamiKuhmonen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting the data back as UTF-8, your `client_encoding` is probably wrong. It can be set per connection and manages the encoding with which the strings are sent back to client. By setting the variable to Latin1 immediately after connecting you can retrieve the strings in the desired encoding.